# Mongoosastic not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoosastic

I am using mongoosastic for performing search operation in mongoose.I have followed the instructions give in this mentioned [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic) but i am not getting the expected output.When i used the search query i am getting

> {
>     "status": "404",
>     "message": "Not Found"
>   }

```
 var express = require('express');
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var mongoosastic = require('mongoosastic')
    /*
    var textSearch = require('mongoose-text-search');
    var lmongo = require('lmongo');
    */
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var app = express();
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/app'));
 var port = 9200;
 app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("listening on", port);
 });
 var router = express.Router();
 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
 }));
 app.use(router);
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/search');
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
 var customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    customerDetails: {

        name: {
            type: String,
            es_indexed: true
        },
        email: String
    },
    Description: String,
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updateAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
 }, {
    strict: false
 }, {
    collection: "customerDetails"
 });

 customerSchema.pre('update', function() {
    this.update({}, {
        $set: {
            updateAt: new Date()
        }
    });
    // next();
 })

 customerSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
    hosts: [
        'localhost:9200'
    ]
 });




 var Customer = mongoose.model('customer', customerSchema),
    stream = Customer.synchronize(),
    count = 0;

 stream.on('data', function(err, doc) {
    count++;
 });
 stream.on('close', function() {
    console.log('indexed ' + count + ' documents!');
 });
 stream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
 });




 /*###################################################################################################*/

 router.route('/cust/index/search') /*enabling search using mongoosastic*/ /*getting as msg not find */
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Customer.search({
            query_string: {
                query: "Sures"
            }
        }, function(err, results) {
            if(err)
                res.send(err);
            res.send(results);
            console.log(results);
        })

    })
```

Comment: Mongoosastic search into an ElasticSearch server not in MongoDB. It gets data from MongoDB and place it in ES to be searched.

Comment: did you find a solution to this?